# Select box not allowing a placeholder with ng-model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a dropdown select box, As soon as i put in `ng-model=` it stops showing a placeholder,

Any ideas why this is happening? I have tried placed `ng-selected`, `Selected` and `default` on the choose option.

Here is the code

```
  <select id="fontChooser" ng-model="eventData.font" placeholder="Test">
            <option value="0" ng-selected="selected">Choose...</option>
            <option value="Times">Times New Roman</option>
            <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
            <option value="ComicSans">Comic Sans</option>
  </select>
```

I'm wanting the choose option to be the placeholder of the select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<option value="">Choose...</option> <!-- leave the value empty -->
```

as the placeholder

[<kbd>Plunker</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/rFH1jTp4bk4tS7jWsk6D?p=preview)

Comment: Cheers, Knew it would be something stupid like that! haha!

Comment: plnkr for anyone : http://plnkr.co/edit/rFH1jTp4bk4tS7jWsk6D?p=preview - feel free to include it in your answer

Comment: I was going too, I had the 10 min wait and forgot about it! ha! i've done it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an ng-init

```
<select id="fontChooser" ng-model="eventData.font" ng-init="eventData.font='Choose'" >
        <option value="Times">Times New Roman</option>
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
        <option value="ComicSans">Comic Sans</option>
```